# Error while setting up react for the first time (event.js:287)

Tags: reactjs, npm, installation, yarnpkg

[error from cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8k1V.png)

I am trying to install react for the first time but I always get an error whenever I run **"npm start"** or **"yarn start"**

```
    C:\react\reactjs>npm install -g yarn
C:\Users\UNCLE  BIGBAY\AppData\Roaming\npm\yarnpkg -> C:\Users\UNCLE  BIGBAY\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarn\bin\yarn.js
C:\Users\UNCLE  BIGBAY\AppData\Roaming\npm\yarn -> C:\Users\UNCLE  BIGBAY\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarn\bin\yarn.js
+ yarn@1.22.4
updated 1 package in 2.163s

C:\react\reactjs>npm start

> reactjs@0.1.0 start C:\react\reactjs
> react-scripts start

Starting the development server...

events.js:287
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
[90m    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:267:19)[39m
[90m    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)[39m
[90m    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)[39m
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
[90m    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:273:12)[39m
[90m    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)[39m
[90m    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)[39m {
  errno: [32m'ENOENT'[39m,
  code: [32m'ENOENT'[39m,
  syscall: [32m'spawn cmd'[39m,
  path: [32m'cmd'[39m,
  spawnargs: [ [32m'/s'[39m, [32m'/c'[39m, [32m'start'[39m, [32m'""'[39m, [32m'/b'[39m, [32m'"http://localhost:3000"'[39m ]
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! reactjs@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the reactjs@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\UNCLE  BIGBAY\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-04-23T00_06_27_219Z-debug.log

C:\react\reactjs>
```

I have tried updating the yarn and even reinstalling it

Comment: I have the same error in Linux, first I have to downgrade with `npm install react-scripts@2.1.8`, next I deleted node_modules ad reinstall with npm install so I did it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could downgrade with help of this script and writing that on your terminal then everything should be work:

```js
create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
npm install react-scripts@2.1.8
npm start
```

This would definitely work. Thanks ))

Answer (score 2):

I had your same problem. I deleted the *node_modules* folder and reinstalled using:

```
npm install
```

After that all works fine.

I find the solution here https://gitmemory.com/issue/facebook/create-react-app/6985/491604318

Answer (score 1):

Please Try After Adding C:\Windows\System32 To Environment Variable Path And Restarting Your Device .

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you are trying to use the [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app)

did you use `npx` to set it up?

```
npx create-react-app joakims-app
cd joakims-app
npm start
```

BTW: It looks like you are running windows - don't know if this is of any help
https://makandracards.com/reactjs-quick/52419-install-reactjs-windows